# Selecting from a list returned by Tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, tuples

```
Select[Tuples[{1, 1/2}, {4, 4}], Total [#] == 15]
```

I want to select all tuples in the result returned by `Tuples` that have total of their elements equal to 15. The answer I got was only `{}`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There [was an excelent answer with an illustration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182163/2036), but I would like to point out the specific mistakes:

- Pure function in the second argmuent should end with `&`
- `Total[#]` by default only sums on the first level, but you need more.